# Stop Autoscroll of UITableView

Tags: ios, scroll, autoscroll, uitableview

So I'm adding rows to a `UITableView` pretty rapidly. The content is an actual twitter stream, and depending on what the user's parameters are, the stream can be quite fast (75 tweets/min or so). I'd like to make it so that as long as the user is at the top of the table view (as in hasn't scrolled down at all) then the page is locked at the top. If, however, they've scrolled down to see a specific quote, that autoscrolling behavior stops and the row that is currently on the screen doesn't move as there are more rows added. AORN, the table view scrolls down as more tweets are added.

Comment: If constant updates aren't the main selling point of this app, why not just load content when the user presses a reload button (or use the pull-down reload arrow)?  Using the internet so much drains the battery, and is bound to be rejected.

Comment: It's a Twitter feed, so real time is key.